# Android - vector drawables in support library v24.0.0

Tags: android, android-support-library

I use some drawables like `abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha` that are packed with the support library.

The support library team switched to vector drawables in v23.2.0 for the first time. I followed the instructions (adding aapt flag, etc) and changed the drawable names in all of my code. For instance `abc_ic_ab_back_material`

But since a lot of people probably didn't like the change, the vector drawables were removed from the following release v23.2.1. So I had to change all of the code again!

Now after updating to v24.0.0, it seems like vector drawables are back again.

Does anyone have a clue about what's going on? Are vector drawables in to stay this time?

Also, the files in `../sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat` still don't seem to updated to reflect the change. So where is v24.0.0 being compiled from exactly?

Comment: I would not recommend using the vector drawables found in the support library. With android studio you can import vector assets that you have created or that are ones that Android has created.

Comment: what do you mean by `the vector drawables were removed from the next release v23.2.1` ? see https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/BZgzpAqkd8G

Comment: @srayhunter any specific reason for that?

Comment: @pskink I meant that in 23.2.1, the vector files like `abc_ic_ab_back_material` were removed from the drawable folder and the png files (like `abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha`) in drawable-__dpi folders were restored like it used to be before the 23.2.0 release.

Comment: ah, sorry, i missed that...

Comment: @goat they make changes to that all the time. If you import the vector drawables into your project you have those - you are not dependent on the support library at all. So when they make changes, you are not affected.

Comment: @srayhunter yes that is a valid concern indeed

Answer (score 2):

VectorDrawable support for pre-Lollipop was added in Support Library 23.2.0, then partially removed in 23.3.0. In 23.4.0 and above (at least 25.1.0), that removed part is back but behind a flag.

To sum up: **in Support Library 23.4.0 to at least 25.1.0, you can get VectorDrawable to work *in some cases***.

I have made [this diagram](https://medium.com/@ferrand.d/can-you-and-should-you-use-vector-drawables-a-cheatsheet-32a2e1cc2ecf) to help.

[image: VectorDrawable cheatsheet]

Comment: This does not entirely answer the question I had asked. I already knew how to add vector drawables. Just wanted to know if there is an official word somewhere from the Android team regarding the confusion. I was only annoyed because they had removed all the png files once again, which meant that I had to change the drawable names to vector again. Anyway the flowchart might be super useful for a lot of people. Thanks for the effort!

Comment: The diagram is awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Yes Vector Drawables are in for this time and they are quite easy to implement too with the Vector Asset Studio.

Implementation of Vectors

1. Right-Click on your /res folder and select Vector Asset Studio
2. You can either choose the vector images provided by default, or can import your own .svg
3. The images are stored in .xml form in your /drawable

Checkout full details here 
https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html

Comment: This does not answer my question! I specifically asked about the vector drawables in the **support library**. Not vector drawables in general. Can you provide a valid source for "Yes Vector Drawables are in for this time" in case you were indeed referring to the vector drawables in support library?